# Configuring Swagger for Multiple Controller in Spring boot microservice

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I am trying to add ReST API docs using Swagger in my microservice which is developing using spring boot. I added properly for one controller. But when I added for two controller. It is not getting listing in swagger-ui.html.

Let me add my findings here,

My swagger config file

```
@EnableSwagger2
@PropertySource("classpath:swagger.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { 
  WebController.class,TestController.class})
@Configuration

public class SwaggerConfig {

    private static final String SWAGGER_API_VERSION = "1.0";
    private static final String LICENSE_TEXT = "License";
    private static final String title = "Spacestudy Framework REST API";
    private static final String description = "docs for test Framework";

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title(title)
                .description(description)
                .license(LICENSE_TEXT)
                .version(SWAGGER_API_VERSION)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket frameworkApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .pathMapping("/")
                .select()
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api.*"))
                .build();
    }
 }
```

My first controller file is ,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/${urlLink}")
@Api(value = "WebControllerAPI", produces = 
 MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

public class WebController {

@PutMapping("/loadMessage/{message}")
@ApiOperation("Insert test Srting ")
@ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = 
  WebController.class)})
public String insertMessage(@PathVariable("message") String message) {
    return message;
 }
}
```

My second controller file is,

```
 @RequestMapping("api/${urlLink}")
 @Api(value = "TestControllerAPI", produces = 
  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class TestController {

  @PutMapping("/loadMessage/{message}")
  @ApiOperation("Insert test Srting ")
  @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = 
    WebController.class)})
   public String insertMessage(@PathVariable("message") String message) {
    return message;
    }
}
```

And I am only getting WebController API doc from Swagger ui. I am not getting TestController End point doc.

I am adding here screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two points:

1. You need to declare `TestController` as `@RestController` as I don't see it in given code.
2. You need to map `TestController` to some different path apart from `api/${urlLink}` (probably `test/api/${urlLink}` or `api/test/${urlLink}`) as it's already allocated to `WebController`.

Comment: Yes. I added with two different url mapping. Its working. I put this simple mistakes. Now Its ready. Thank you Mr.Yogesh Badke. Thank you for your guidance and spending time with my issue.

Comment: I have the same setup, however when I've configured it with swagger-ui my swagger UI doesn't redirect properly.

Answer (score 3):

Add it in your docket configuration and no need to be specific with the path..

.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))